# Using regex to match string1 but not if string1 is accompanied by string 2

Tags: regex

I need to only select the strings that contain the word 'Rack', however, if the string contains both 'Rack' and 'Shelf' I don't want it to be selected.

```
blah/blah/Rack 1/Box 5/Row 2/Cell 3
blah/blah/Rack 2/Box 4/Row 2/Cell 3
blah/blah/Rack 4/Box 3/Row 2/Cell 3 
blah/blah/Shelf 1/Rack 1/Box 1/Row 2/Cell 3
blah/blah/Box 3/Row 2/Cell 3
```

I tried something like below but it will still select the last record.

```
(^((?!Shelf).)*$)
```

Comment: What OS/database and/or software are you using to do the regex in?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?!.*?\bShelf\b).*?\bRack\b.*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eO3bA5/1)

`(?!.*?\bShelf\b)` is negative lookahead to fail the match if `Shelf` is found in the match.

Comment: I don't understand why this works even if Shelf is behind Rack, could you explain please?

Comment: It is due to lookahead `(?!.*?\bShelf\b)` which negates matching `Shelf` anywhere after line start.